# if/else does not work in Perl

Tags: perl, if-statement

I have the following code:

```
if ($strand_hit eq "-" and $strand_key ne "+") {
    $upstream_exonic_antisense{$key} = $hit;
}
elsif ($strand_hit eq "-" and $strand_key eq "-") {
    $upstream_exonic_sense{$key} = $hit;
    print "hola\n";
                    }
elsif ($strand_hit eq "-" and $strand_key eq ".") {
    $upstream_exonic_unknown{$key} = $hit;
}
elsif ($strand_hit eq "+" and $strand_key ne "-") {
    $downstream_exonic_antisense{$key} = $hit;
}
elsif ($strand_hit eq "+" and $strand_key eq "+") {
    $downstream_exonic_sense{$key} = $hit;
    print "hola\n";
}
elsif ($strand_hit eq "+" and $strand_key eq ".") {
    $downstream_exonic_unknown{$key} = $hit;
}
elsif ($strand_hit eq ".") {
    $updown_exonic_unknown{$key} = $hit;
}
else {
    print $strand_key.$strand_hit."\n";
    next;
}
```

The variables `$strand_hit` and `$strand_key` can be `+`, `-`, or `.`. However, the elsif(s) do not work and everything go to the `else` statement... Do you know why?

Thanks.

Comment: I would guess that you have entered `$strand_hit` and `$strand_key` from the keyboard and failed to `chomp` them. Please `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print Dumper($strand_hit, $strand_key)` to diagnose the problem

Comment: I would suggest you add a print statement before the if to print out the length of $strand_hit and $strand_key.  Such as: print "length fo hit: " . length($strand_hit) . " Length of key: ".length($strand_key) . "\n";  If the scalars are not exactly a length of 1, the comparisons will not work.

Comment: length=1... I should say that if I change the `elsif` for a simple `if` everything works... I don't know why.

Comment: @user2886545 `elsif` branches guarantee that only ONE elsif branch is executed. Is that what you want?

Comment: Don't you think that if "if and else don't work in perl", someone would have noticed at some point in the past 25 years?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the possibility that you have not chomped your incoming data, in your first test, the second and third elsifs cannot be executed. I suspect the rest of the tests are similarly flawed.

Refactoring:

```
if ($strand_hit eq "-") {
  if ($strand_key ne "+") { # should this be eq ??
     $upstream_exonic_antisense{$key} = $hit;
  } elsif ($strand_key eq "-") {
     $upstream_exonic_sense{$key} = $hit;
     print "hola\n";
  } elsif ($strand_key eq ".") {
      $upstream_exonic_unknown{$key} = $hit;
  }
} elsif ($strand_hit eq "+") {
  if ($strand_key ne "-") { # should this be eq?
     $downstream_exonic_antisense{$key} = $hit;
  } elsif ($strand_key eq "+") {
     $downstream_exonic_sense{$key} = $hit;
     print "hola\n";
  } elsif ($strand_key eq ".") {
     $downstream_exonic_unknown{$key} = $hit;
  }
}  elsif ($strand_hit eq ".") {
  $updown_exonic_unknown{$key} = $hit;
} else {
   print $strand_key.$strand_hit."\n";
   next;
}
```

Lets assume $strand_hit eq '-' for the moment.
If $strand_key eq '+' none of the above if statements will be executed. The first statement will be executed for all other values of $strand_key

Now assume $strand_hit eq '-'. The first statement in the block of if elses is the only one that can be executed again.

I suggest you join the two values together and have `if` statements for the two character string. It will be easier to read. Multiple elsifs with and clauses are the work of the devil...

Answer (score 2):

Either there is an issue with one or both of the variables not being exactly what you think (for instance, having a newline at the end), or the code doesn't *appear* to be working because it is buggy:  If the if condition is true, the first and second elsif conditions will be true too, but never get reached because the if branch will be taken.  Similarly, if the third elsif condition is true, the forth and fifth elsif branches will never be taken.  Can you describe in English what you expect your code to do?

Answer (score 2):

As was already stated, most likely your variables contain artifacts such as return characters.  Always debug your code by printing out the variables to the console in situations like this.  `print "'$var'\n";`

I'd also like to introduce you to another method for this type of if/else situation.  You can create a dispatch table that holds anonymous subroutines to be executed based off the values you're comparing against.  This can be a useful construct when the code that you're working with is especially simple, just long.

```
my %dispatch_table = (
    '-' => {
        '+' => sub { $upstream_exonic_antisense{$key} = $hit; },
        '-' => sub { $upstream_exonic_sense{$key} = $hit; print "hola\n"; },
        '.' => sub { $upstream_exonic_unknown{$key} = $hit; },
        },
    '+' => {
        '-' => sub { $downstream_exonic_antisense{$key} = $hit; },
        '+' => sub { $downstream_exonic_sense{$key} = $hit; print "hola\n"; },
        '.' => sub { $downstream_exonic_unknown{$key} = $hit; },
        },
    );

if (my $sub = $dispatch_table{$strand_hit}{$strand_key}) {
    $sub->();
} 
elsif ($strand_hit eq ".") {
    $updown_exonic_unknown{$key} = $hit;
}
else {
    warn "strand_key = '$strand_key', strand_hit = '$strand_hit'\n";
    next;
}
```

Note how I've enclosed the else debugging message with single quotes to ensure you can see if there is any artifact spacing inside the variables.

Comment: Despite the fact I also answered this question, I prefer this solution as a more comprehensive fix to the problem